# Change app name dynamically from API data?

Tags: java, android

I need to change app name dynamically from web service data. 
For ex: If default app name is "WhatsApp", I need to change it to "Facebook" by getting data from API.

How is it possible?

Comment: What is it that you are trying ti achieve by doing this? Maybe there is another way of doing what you are trying to do, without having to change the app name

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible, You can't change app name dynamically from web. Due to security reasons.